# Using regex_search in c++ and library <regex>

Tags: c++, regex

I want to use regex_search member function in  in c++ 11.

However, i can not find correct answers for a given regular expression.

The example is as follows:

Target string: "abcd cd abefcd ababcddecd"

Given regular expression: "ab.*cd" - this regular expression is based on POSIX extended gramer.

Expected result: abcd, abcd cd, abcd cd abefcd, abcd cd abefcd ababcd, abcd cd abefcd ababcddecd,
                 abefcd, abefcd ababcd, abefcd ababcddecd, ababcd, ababcddecd

library is not familiar for me.

So, i don't know what to do for getting expected result in the example above.

Source code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    regex re("ab.*cd", regex::extended);
    smatch m;
    string s = "abcd cd abefcd ababcddecd";

    // TO DO??

    /*
    while(regex_search(s, m, re)){
        for(auto x:m) cout << x << " ";
        cout << endl;
        s = m.suffix().str();
    }
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's good you post the expected result, but what is the *actual* result?

Comment: It is nice you copied the sample provided at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/ but what did YOU try

Comment: Are you, perhaps, using gcc? Most gcc distributions have a *completely* broken `<regex>`.

Comment: I use the g++ when i compile the code in linux system.

Actually the code is compiled with the command line as follows 

g++ -g main.cpp -std=c++11

is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    regex e("(a.*cd)", regex::extended);
    string s = R"(abcd cd abefcd ababcddecd)";
    string match = "";
    size_t i = 0;
    while (s.size() > i)
    {
        smatch m;
        string ss = s.substr(0, i);

        regex_search(ss, m, e);
        if (m.size() > 1 && m[1] != match) {
            cout << m[1] << endl; 
            match = m[1];
        }
        i++;
    }
        cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep.

I execute your code. But, the code is not working correctly.

Actually, it is not return any matched string for a given regular expression.

I don't know what is problem.


I compiled the code using commend line as follows:

g++ -g main.cpp -std=c++11

is this compile option correct? if not how can i compile the code?

Comment: I executed the code in VS-2013 (Express). g++ regex module is not considered 'complete' yet.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` operation in regular expressions is **greedy**: it eats everything that it can without breaking the rest of the match. So when you search `"abxxxabyyyab"` with `ab.*ab` the regular expression matches the **entire** string; the `.*` matches `"xxxabyyy"`. What you're looking for is a **non-greedy** search, where the `*` consumes the **shortest** substring that doesn't break the match. To do that, use `*?`. When you search `"abxxxabyyyab"` with `ab.*?ab` the regular expression matches `"abxxxab"` and the `.*?` matches `"xxx"`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this problem cause the library  in C++11.

I implement short code for the example described in original question above with the library.

However, i can not get correct answer. regex_search returns just 0 whenever.

So. I use  in Boost library for implement the example.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    boost::regex e("ab.*cd", boost::regex::extended);
    std::string s("abcd cd abefcd ababcddecd");
    boost::smatch m;
    std::map<std::string, int> mm;
    // I use a map for prevent redundant duplication of matched string

    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= (s.size() - i); j++){
            std::string ss = s.substr(i, j);
            boost::smatch m;
            if(boost::regex_search(ss, m, e)){
                int temp = mm[m[0]];
                if(temp == 0){
                    mm[m[0]] = 1; 
                    cout << "Match string: " << m[0] << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Makefile is as follows:

```
CC = g++   

FLAG = -g
FLAG_I = -I/usr/include
FLAG_L = -L/usr/lib -lboost_regex    

OBJECTS = main.o
TARGET = main

$(Target) : $(OBJECTS)
$(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(FLAG_L)
main.o : main.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAG) -c main.cpp $(FLAG_I)
```

I get correct answer well using this code in linux machine such as fedora 19 with Boost library.

```
[user@localhost test]#make
g++ -g -c main.cpp -I/usr/include
g++ -o main main.o -L/usr/lib -lboost_regex
[user@localhost test]#./main
Match string: abcd
Match string: abcd cd
Match string: abcd cd abefcd
Match string: abcd cd abefcd ababcd
Match string: abcd cd abefcd ababcddecd
Match string: abefcd
Match string: abefcd ababcd
Match string: abefcd ababcddecd
Match string: ababcd
Match string: ababcddecd
Match string: abcddecd
[user@localhost test]#
```

-end-